# How to aggregate data in SQL into a format of every two weeks (showing date of beginning of first week)

Tags: sql, date, week-number

What is the best way to aggregate data in SQL so that it's broken up into two week periods. So say for a given three month period (which is what I'm trying to solve here) I work for a company that sells produce and they sell cases of tomatoes. I need to show for every two weeks how many tomatoes a customer has purchased. If this was weekly I could aggregate the results using one of the below methods...
  cast(DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, min(h.document_date)), -1) as date)
OR 
  DATEPART(ww,cast(h.document_date as date))

Either of the above methods would give me weekly results, but i need the results of two weeks worth where the date showing is the beginnning of the two week period. So, for example if I was running this for April 2019 the first row of the results would show '3/31/2019' and would have the cases purchased through the 13th of april (since that's two weeks worth of cases). The next row would then have a date of '4/14/2019'.
I hope this makes sense.

I have solved this issue by using a work around but I'm still unsure how someone would aggregate a query for every two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

taking your example

```
DATEPART(ww,cast(h.document_date as date))
```

could you make all the odd week to be the previous even week?

```
floor(DATEPART(ww,cast(h.document_date as date))/2)*2
```

Alternatively, if you want the actual start of the date.
Find the difference in days between the first day of 2 weeks period and your date, then subtract from it

Try this :

```
DATEADD(day,  -DATEDIFF( day , '2019-03-31' , OrderDate) % 14, OrderDate)
```

Replace the 2019-03-31 with 2019-04-07 if you want to start your 2 week period with different Sunday.

Comment: I will try this and see what happens. I actually did something somewhat similar by using a query to filter to only even weeks and then a subquery to get the odd weeks and added the odd week values to the previous even week. It works but it takes a while to run (and it's more or less a hack).

Comment: Actually your original code ...  
floor(DATEPART(ww,cast(h.document_date as date))/2)*2 
...worked perfectly! thank you.

Comment: Nice. I have add my original code back :P glad I have helped.